# How can I modify my if statement so that the values print out after every full second?

Tags: java

So basically, I have a variable, `time`, and would like the program to print the other values for every full second.

For example if I plug in 100, it should print out 20 seconds only.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CannonBlaster {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
     final double DELTA_T = 0.01; //initiating all variables
     final double G = 9.81; 
     double s = 0.0; 
     double time = 0.0; 
     double second = 0;


    System.out.println("What's the initial velocity?: ");//asking for the initial velocity
    double v =input.nextDouble();


    while (s >= 0.0) //while loop is used. As long as the height isn't negative it will continue to go.
    {

    s += v * DELTA_T; //demonstrates the change of velocity and position for every .01 second.
    v -= G * DELTA_T; 
    time += DELTA_T; 

    System.out.println("The time is: "+time+" "+(double) Math.floor(time)+" "+Math.round(time * 1000) / 1000);
    second=Math.round(time * 1) / 1;
    if ((double) Math.floor(time) ==time)
     {
       System.out.println("Approximated position: "+ s); 
       System.out.println("Formula's position: "+(100.0 * time - (time*time * G) / 2.0)); //prints out the formula values and the loop values.

     }


    }




}
```

Excuse the mess, it's just I've been trying different ways to get to work, but found none so far.

Comment: Either use `Thread.sleep(1000L)` or use a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: Dude, I'm a novice! I don't know how to use any of those! I'm going to look it up!. I'm trying to print out every time the variable time is a whole number.

Comment: Here's your opportunity to learn.

Comment: I think Javi means every simulated second, rather than elapsed second.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that double doesn't have the kind of accuracy you're looking for, so it doesn't count by an even .01 each iteration as your output clearly shows.  The solution is to use [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/math/BigDecimal.html).  I rewrote the program a bit...

```
package test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CannonBlaster {

    private static final double G = 9.81;
    private static final BigDecimal DELTA_T = new BigDecimal(0.01);
    private static final double DELTA_T_DOUBLE = DELTA_T.doubleValue();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double s = 0.0;
        BigDecimal time = new BigDecimal(0.0);
        double time_double = 0.0;

        System.out.println("What's the initial velocity?: ");// asking for the
                                                                // initial
                                                                // velocity
        double v = input.nextDouble();

        // As long as the height isn't negative it will continue to go.
        while (s >= 0.0)
        {

            s += v * DELTA_T_DOUBLE;
            v -= G * DELTA_T_DOUBLE;
            time = time.add(DELTA_T);
            time_double = time.doubleValue();
            if (time.doubleValue()%1==0) {
                System.out.printf("Approximated position at t=%3ds is %10.6f.\n", time.intValue(), s);
                // prints out the formula values and the loop values.
                System.out.println("Formula's position: " + formula(time_double)); 

            }

        }
    }

    private static double formula(double x){
        return 100.0 * x - (x * x * G) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your time step, `DELTA_T`, is not exactly representable as a `double` value.  Each iteration accumulates this small error, and you can see this in the `time` values that get printed out.

Usually it's preferable to avoid this problem when comparing two floating point numbers by comparing the absolute difference between the two numbers to some "small" value, where "small" is defined by the problem / magnitude of numbers you are working with.  `DELTA_T` fits pretty well here, so you could use this comparison for a per-second time step:

```
  if (Math.abs(time - Math.round(time)) < DELTA_T)
  {
     // Other code here
  }
```

Alternatively, for a more generalized time step, in `PRINT_INTERVAL`:

```
  final double PRINT_INTERVAL = 0.1;

  // Other code...

  if (Math.abs(time / PRINT_INTERVAL - Math.round(time / PRINT_INTERVAL)) < DELTA_T)
  {
     // Other code here
  }
```